# triangle inscribed in a triangle: Minimum length of two sides

Tags: geometry, triangles

Have been reading Shwarz's proof of the minimal permiter of a triangle inscribed in another triangle as outlined in chapter VII of Courant and Robbins' "What is Mathematics" and they assume (on pg. 349 of second edition) that the minimal perimeter provided by "altitude" inscribed triangle construction would also be minimal on the sum of any two of its sides (let's call each of these pairwise sums the "partial perimeter" and the set of all three such sums the "partial perimeters").

I don't see how this can be assumed.  Does anyone have a counterexample or demonstration that the inscribed triangle with the smallest permieter will also have the smallest sum of any two of its sides?  If the inscribed triangle of minimal perimeter does not minimize the partial permiters, then can somebody characterize the inscribed triangle that provides a minimal partial perimeter?

Comment: So you mean... find the inscribed triangle T with side lengths s1, s2, s3, that minimizes the minimum of {s1 + s2, s2 + s3, s3 + s1} ?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what you're saying, so reproducing the relevant portion could be helpful. $\quad$ I'm guessing that you're asking why out of the pedal triangles, the orthic triangle (formed by the feet of the perpendiculars) have the minimal perimeter, but that also requires the assumption that the triangle is acute. $\quad$ With such an assumption, the reflection principle argument works well for your desired conclusion.

Comment: @DanielV that's correct.

Comment: A counter example I think: if the outer triangle is equilateral then the resulting orthic will have partial perimeters greater than the altitutde of the outer triangle.  Thus, an inscribed triangle exists of a lesser partial perimeter with one vertex A coincident with one of the orthic vertices and another vertex arbitrarily close to the vertex of the larger triangle opposite A.